# Authorized header rejected in dockerized spring application

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker, nginx, spring-security

I have a react and a spring boot application. Both running inside a docker container.

Here is my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /api {
       proxy_pass   http://app-backend:8087/api;
       proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Here is backend security config

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors()
                .configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://app.myapp.fr", "http://localhost:3000"));
                    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
                    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                    return configuration;
                })
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(POST, "/connexion").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(POST, "/inscription").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(POST, "/activation").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();

        final JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter(this.profileService, this.jwtTokenUtil, this.tokenHeader);
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .cacheControl();
    }
```

This config works well locally.
On my staging VM

i have this error in backend container

```
o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Reject: 'https://app.myapp.fr' origin is not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

So this has nothing to do with your dockerised application exactly. You have to handle the CORS either on your proxy layer or at backend.. the current domain `https://app.myapp.fr` is not authorised to access your application.

To handle at backend [refer this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

To allow all the hosts , modify your nginx config to this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /api {
       proxy_pass   http://app-backend:8087/api;
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "app.myapp.fr";
       proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

If incase the origin could be anything than just your domain, maybe try this complete security compromised approach:

```
    location /api {
       proxy_pass   http://app-backend:8087/api;
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * ;
       proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    }
```

Learn more about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).